# How to redirect portal view JSP to another JSP inside same WAR File on click of a link?

Tags: jsp, portal, jsr286

Hi i have a simple requirement but really confused to implement that.
I have a portletvview.jsp and there's a link in that page. On click of that link i should open a pop-up page, which is my second jsp.
How to implement this in JSR-286 Basic Portlet ?
Would really appreciate any help..

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 0):

I didnt get the complete question. But From what ever i understood you need something like this

Put this function in javacript file or in the header tag of your html page

```
 function myPopup() 
     {
            window.open( "place the link for the next jsp here" )
     }

<input type="button" onClick="myPopup()" value="POP!">
```

Comment: You need this as well
<input type="button" onClick="myPopup()" value="POP!">

Comment: Use code formatting when writing code and you can edit your post also.